# What shall we do with "Why do we rely on computers in critical fields?"

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I am soliciting discussion and advice on what to do about the question [Why do we rely on computers in critical fields?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/153158/755).

When it was [originally posted](https://cs.stackexchange.com/revisions/153158/1), the question was "Are computers really reliable?"  Then, it hit the Hot Network Questions list, and at some point later, it was edited to ask "Why do we rely on computers in critical fields?".

Unfortunately, this means we now have an odd collection of answers.  We have some answers that were posted early in response to "Are computers really reliable?", that explain how reliable computers are.  And we have some answers that were posted later in response to "Why do we rely on computers in critical fields?", that explain why we rely on computers.  Both of these kinds of answers have value.  And perhaps because it has hit Hot Network Questions, many of these answers have large numbers of upvotes.

What, if anything, should we do about this?

If we hadn't received so many answers, the normal response to an edit that changes the meaning of the question and invalidates prior answers would be to roll back the edit.  However in this case anything we do will render some answers irrelevant.  If we roll it back to its prior state, then we invalidate the newest answers.  If we leave it as it is, then the oldest answers have been invalidated by the edit.  I am requesting help in figuring out the best way to handle this situation.

Comment: Maybe the best way will be to edit the question to clarify that it was edited and previously asked something different. (I might be biased though, as I wrote the first answer that OP accepted before subsequently changing the question.)